# How to compile HTML files into CHM file?

Tags: html, delphi, chm, helpfile

How in my code (Delphi) to make CHM files from a bunch of HTML (with linked image files)? Details needed, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe there are libs/components to do that. Personnaly, I made it myself as it is quite easy.

Your application should

- list all files to include
- Create HHC + HHP + HHK files content-
- call command line hhc.exe with HHP parameter

As an example, have a look to **DelphiCodeToDoc** CHM generator.
Read `uDocGenCHM_Tools.pas` and `uDocGeneratorChm.pas` in svn repository of my project (too large to post here!).
https://dephicodetodoc.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dephicodetodoc/trunk/DelphiCodeToDoc/Source/Generator/Chm/

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out, with sample code it'll be great.

Comment: I accept this answer because it provides example codes in Delphi. But other answers are great too! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 8):

The normal way to do this is to use `hhc` from Microsoft's [HTML Help Workshop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169%28VS.85%29.aspx) to build a help project, specified in a `.hhp` file. You can write the `.hpp` file yourself, and all its auxiliary files. Or, more commonly, you can use a 3rd party help authoring tool of which there are many.

I don't see where Delphi comes into the building of the `.chm` file, but if I've missed something then please update your question to add more details.

Comment: Documentation generation tools?

Comment: @Marco I'm sorry, I don't follow your comment.

Comment: Documentation tools written in Delphi are a valid application for a CHM generating library. I know because we did it because of that :) (in reply to your "don't see where Delphi comes into..")

Comment: @Marco I still don't understand! I must be particularly slow today.

Comment: @Marco OK, I think you mean that the OP may want to write his/her own help authoring tool and use Delphi code to generate the .chm file. And that's the crux of your answer. If it were me, I'd be inclined to shell out to `hhc` as do most of the professional packages, but that's obviously a personal preference.

Comment: hhw afaik is not certified for Windows 7 deployment. If the documentation application is for internal use, no problem, but if you need to deploy, it is not so simple. That doesn't mean the  below package is ideal, far from it, but there are multiple tradeoffs, and it is not a simple "by default" decision. Trust me, I worked on below app for a reason :-)

Comment: @marco I'm using Flare on Windows 7 which relies on html help workshop. I don't perceive deployment to be an issue.

Comment: It is not deploying yourself as experienced IT, but supporting deployment of your app with dependancies with sb else.  As said, we mainly did it because our main servers are Linux. 64-bit even. But several users of the package commented on its use.

Answer (score 3):

Free Pascal includes a CHM read/write library (without dependancies), and SVN versions also contain a basic commandline CHM compiler. The license is the same as the rest of FPC's Library, LGPL with static linking exception, so fine for commercial use.

I think it should be fairly easy to port to Delphi.

The somewhat outdate package page for this package is

http://wiki.freepascal.org/chm

The package was originally developed for FPC's library documentation tool fpdoc. (Documentation is generated nightly in some cases, and all FPC/Lazarus' servers are Unix)